# How to stop sliding after last image in FilmRoll jQuery carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, carousel

I want to stop [FilmRoll jQuery carousel](http://straydogstudio.github.io/film_roll/) after first loop then disable the next button. But user can still see the previous button which is then disabled on first slide.

Any suggestion?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  /*var film_roll = new FilmRoll({
    container: '#portfolioSlider',
    vertical_center: true,
    hover: false,
    scroll: false
  });*/


  var film_roll = new FilmRoll({
    container: '#portfolioSlider2',
    vertical_center: true,
    hover: false,
    scroll: false,
    move_on_start: false,
    offset: -111
  });
});

$('#portfolioSlider2').on('film_roll:moved', function(event) {
  alert(film_roll.index);
  if ( film_roll.index == film_roll.children.length - 1 ) {
    alert("hello");
    film_roll.clearScroll();
  }
});
```

Comment: Post something you have done and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: thx for your reply...plz see this crousal....http://straydogstudio.github.io/film_roll   /....i just want to stop that infine loop...i want only 1 loop

Comment: That is the library you want to implement. I am asking for your code. I mean how much you have progressed using that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe just removing the prev/next arrows would be a solution for you...

```
// Remove the prev arrow
setTimeout(function(){
  $(document).find('.film_roll_prev').hide();
},600);

$('#portfolioSlider2').on('film_roll:moved', function(event) {
  console.log(film_roll.index);

  if ( film_roll.index == film_roll.children.length - 1 ) {
    console.log("hello");

    // Remove the next arrow
    $('.film_roll_next').hide();
    film_roll.clearScroll();
  }
});
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/brvomG?editors=1111)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just do first loop then change `scroll` to `true`.

Updated code:

```
$(function() {

  var film_roll = new FilmRoll({
    container: '#portfolioSlider2',
    vertical_center: true,
    hover: false,
    scroll: true, //to start loop at first
    move_on_start: false,
    offset: -111
  });


  $('#portfolioSlider2').on('film_roll:moved', function(event) {
    if (film_roll.index == film_roll.children.length - 1) {
      $('.film_roll_next').hide();
      $('.film_roll_prev').show();
      film_roll.clearScroll(); //stops loop after first round
    } else if (film_roll.index === 0) {
      $('.film_roll_prev').hide();
      $('.film_roll_next').show();
    } else {
      $('.film_roll_prev').show();
      $('.film_roll_next').show();
    }
  });
});
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/JzN5vB8nDU4tRA7Fm0LW).

Comment: @Priyavrat You cannot make two answers accepted. Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.